# How can I clear the "crawl errors" of Google webmaster tools?

Tags: google-search-console

How can I clear the "crawl errors" of Google webmaster tools? On my webmaster tools page, there are some "Not found" crawl errors dating back two years which I cleared up a long time ago, but they are still hanging around on webmaster tools. I thought they would go away naturally once the mistaken links were fixed, but they don't seem to. Is there any way to clear old crawl errors manually?

Comment: I too am having this error, although mine date back as far as 2 years. And have not found a solution.

Comment: hey like i put ma site.. n crawl found 25 errors 404 but wat link it shows to me when i am opening it they are working well but why  it says itz a error  :S plzz tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve 404 errors (and get them to stop appearing in Webmaster Tools) by implementing a 301 redirect from the old URI to a valid URI - if the links were incorrect to begin with, go ahead and redirect them to the content they were supposed to link to.

Comment: The point is that the page they say links to the page no longer links to it.

Comment: @Kinopiko - It's still a good idea to alert Googlebot to the change with a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 2):

You can only "clear" the errors by fixing them. If the pages return 404 Not Found then that is still an error. It's likely that the page is being linked from somewhere else on the web.

If there is an equivalent page, add a 301 redirect to that page and the error will disappear in a few weeks.

Look at where the 404 link comes from and see if you are able to fix it. For example if it's from a blog post, the site owner may be interested in fixing it. If it's from a forum you are probably out of luck.

EDIT based on comment: if the page no longer links to you, check that google's cache of the page isn't an old one. If the link was only recently removed it will take several weeks for GWT to update.

Answer (score 0):

I've  done  301 redirects  when  you  click  now  on the   404 page  it  goes  to  where  it  should  but the  error  won't  clear  from  webmaster  tools  and  its  been  more  than  a  month  almost  2  ,  additionally    a bunch  of  non existing  pages   that  where  at  some  point  on the   sitemap  but  have  since  been  removed  and   the  sitemap rebuilt  still  show  as  404 ,  this  pages  BTW   are  not  referenced on  any  external  URL and  no  longer  exist  on  the  site  coding   or  sitemaps  , sitemap crawling change  time  where    updated  to .  still  this  errors  remain  like  they  are  stuck  on   Google  cache  the  pages  BTW  they are  not indexed  on  Google   the  wrong  URLs  and  the  non existing   .

so  i've  search and  search  and   i  found  no  answer  on  how  to   get   Google  to clear  this  pages   that don't  exixt  and are  not linked  anywhere  anymore

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix 404 not found webmaster tools errors (I assume you already know how to access .htaccess file of your wordpress blog):

1. First and very crucial, backup your .htaccess file, by downloading it and save it in your hard drive.
2. Once you done the step (1) above, go to your Google webmaster tools, copy the URL which causes 404 not found webmaster tools errors one by one, if you have many.

Copy it in notepad, that’s the easiest method.

1. Go back to your .htaccess file, add this code:

redirect 301 /2010/02/13/change-homelink-to-your-own-created-page http://www.timesnewstoday.com/change-homelink-to-your-own-created-page

The code above should be in one line. That’s one of my example post that i did redirect.

Replace my URL address with yours.

What that code will do, is redirected the 404 not found webmaster tools errors URL old page to the new one.